# Docker containers restart order

Tags: docker, containers

I have two containers running on Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS.
One of them is Selenium Grid and the second one is Python container that works in the connection with mentioned above Selenium container.

How can I get these two containers correctly restarted after system poweroff or reboot?

I tried this:
 `docker update --restart [on-failure] [always] [unless-stopped] container_grid docker update --restart [on-failure] [always] [unless-stopped] container_python`

The Selenium Grid container restarts correctly, but Python container keeps restarting in a loop.

As I can suppose it cannot by some reason establish connection to the second one, exits with the code 1 and keeps restarting.

How can I avoid this? Maybe there is a solution that adds delay or sets the order of containers restart after turning on the system? Or should I simply add some delay in Python code because there is no any simple solution to this?

I am not software developer but automation engineer so could somebody help me with the solution. Maybe it would e Docker Compose or something else.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is not solution in plain Docker itself as far as I know. Check questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636303/docker-container-dependency which explain this for Kubernetes and Docker Compose or this docker site https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try adding delay in Python script.

Answer (score 0):

So) Solved this problem via crontab.

Selenium container starts in accordance with "--restart on-failure" option.

My Python container starts with a delay in accordance with crontab command:

```
@reboot sleep 20 && docker start [python_container]
```